# How to Serve Specific Files in a Private S3 Bucket via CloudFront and Route 53 with Query Strings in React App?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have developed a one-page React application hosted in an S3 bucket, which is configured to be private, and it's served through a CloudFront distribution with Route 53 for DNS. The S3 bucket is configured to allow access only through the CloudFront distribution via a bucket policy.

Everything works smoothly, but I've encountered an issue when I tried to load an iframe with dangerouslySetInnerHTML. The source of the iframe is set to something like this:

`https://THE_URL_OF_MY_APPLICATION/viewer.html?MY_QUERY_STRINGS`

Unfortunately, this results in an "Error 503 Access Denied" due to the S3 bucket's private settings, which only allow the default root object (set as /index.html) to be accessible.

My question is, how can I make the viewer.html accessible while still maintaining the security of the S3 bucket and the proper use of CloudFront? Is there a way to allow specific files with query strings to be accessed while keeping others protected?

Any guidance or solutions to this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!